# Same person swapping FirstName and LastName - Vice Versa

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My boss asked me to come up with a script to find `FirstName=LastName` and Vice Versa `LastName=FirstName` in SQL database for all clients.

Example:

```
ID  FirstName   LastName    Branch      Date        Loan
648 Joe         Blow        New York    2017.04.24  6000
784 Blow        Joe         New York    2017.09.01  2000
```

Here is my script however it's not populating what I'm supposed to get:

```
select C1.[Same Person], C1.FirstName, C1.LastName, C1.AccountId, C1.Loan, C1.branch, C1.DateOpened
from    
(
    select a.Accountid, C.FirstName, C.LastName, a.Status, d.Description branch
        , a.DateOpened, a.TotalAdvances + a.TotalRefinance Loan
        , case when C.FirstName = C.FirstName then C.FirstName when C.LastName = C.LastName then C.LastName 
        else 'Unknown'  end as 'Same Person' 
    from Account a
    inner join Client C on A.ClientPk = c.Pk
    left outer join Branch d on a.branchpk = d.pk
) C1
```

The output for the above script is as shown;

```
| Same Person  | FirstName  | LastName    | AccountId | Loan   | Branch   | Date       |  
| :----------: | :--------: | :---------: | :--------:|:------:|:--------:|:---------: |  
| Unknown      | NULL       | NULL        | 6789      |   3000 | New York | 2017-09-21 |   
| Unknown      | NULL       | NULL        | 8901      |   7000 | New York | 2017-06-20 |  
| KAUKESA      | KAUKESA    | KAMEN       | 6789      |   5000 | New York | 2017-02-19 |
```

My script should generate the above table as one client swamping names because most of his records are the same.

Comment: If you can post your sample output after comparing first name to last name, that would be helpful.

Comment: See updated question for script output

Comment: Your example output data isn't the result of your input data. Nor does it explain how you want to deal with the fact that if you find a match the amount and date might be different - so you can't just show them in the same line unless you show both amounts. You really need to clarify the problem further for assistance as how this is best solved depends on the full problem.

Comment: Since the amount and the date are going to be different, I want to show them in both rows, that is why I place a column so if it finds a match then it should display the name in the column "Same Person". I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish but here is a query to detect if there is another client with the names swapped - maybe this will help you develop your full solution.

```
select FirstName, LastName, AccountId, Loan, Branch, [Date]
  , (select top 1 PK from dbo.Client C1 where C1.LastName = C.FirstName and C1.FirstName = C.LastName and C1.PK != C.PK) [Possible Swapped Duplicate Id]
from dbo.Account A
inner join dbo.Client C on C.PK = A.ClientPK
left outer join dbo.Branch D on D.PK = A.BranchPK
```